# Convert boolean expression to 3 input NOR

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I was taking a look at this link http://lizarum.com/assignments/boolean_algebra/chapter3.html to try and solve an equation I have. The original equation is:

H = MC + MC' + CRD + M'CD'

I simplified it to
H = M + CRD + M'CD'

Here is my attempt:

```
H = ((M + CRD + M'CD')')'
H = ((M)' * (CRD)' * (M'CD')')'
H = (((M)')' + ((CRD)')' + ((M'CD')')'
H = ((M')' + (C'+ R' + D')' + (M + C' + D)')'
```

Is that final equation a 3 input NOR equation? I have a feeling that I'm missing a step that makes the first parentheses into three variables.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, notice that `M C + M C' = M`

This simplifies your equation to

```
H = M + CRD + M'CD'
```

You can then leave out the `M'`. If it were `false`, `M` would be true and thus `H`.

```
 H = M + CRD + CD'
```

This allows you to factor-out `C`:

```
 H = M + C(RD + D')
```

Term `D` in the parentheses can be left out (same argument as above)

```
 H = M + C(R + D')
```

The final result is:

```
 H = M + CR + CD'
```

You could have arrived at this result using a [Karnaugh-Veitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) map.

Convince yourself asking [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28M%20and%20C%29%20or%20%28M%20and%20not%20C%29%20or%20%28C%20and%20R%20and%20D%29%20or%20%28not%20M%20and%20C%20and%20not%20D%29).